# How to get facebook recommendations count in php

Tags: php, facebook

Can any one help how to get facebook recommended count in php.

I search for facebook api but i dint found any.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Recommendation is a Like. You can see it in the reference of the like button :

> `action` - the verb to display on the button. Options: 'like', 'recommend'

To get the counts for a URL (here `http://stackoverflow.com`), you can make an FQL call :

```
 SELECT url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count
 FROM link_stat WHERE url="http://stackoverflow.com"
```

## Call directly

```
$fql = 'SELECT url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count
        FROM link_stat WHERE url="http://stackoverflow.com"';
$json = file_get_contents('https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=' . urlencode($fql));
```

And `$json` will contain :

```
[
    {
        "url"           : "http://stackoverflow.com",
        "share_count"   : 1353,
        "like_count"    : 332,
        "comment_count" : 538,
        "total_count"   : 2223
    }
]
```

You have here :

- `share_count` : the counts of shares for the URL
- `like_count` : the count of likes (= recommendations)
- `comment_count` : the count of comments in Facebook below shares of that link
- `total_count` : the sum of theses 3 counts

You can read json in PHP with `json_decode` :

```
$data = json_decode($json);
echo  $data[0]->like_count;
```

## Use the Facebook PHP SDK

**EDIT** : As Rufinus pointed out int the comments of his answer, for stability reasons, if you are on a long term project and not just a quick experiment you should use the Facebook PHP SDK ([see on github](http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk)) to make FQL queries : **Facebook is more and more closing public access** (read without access token) to its API (see [this blog post on Facebook developers blog](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/509/)). Even like here when theses queries are not related to any user : the SDK is using the app access token to make the query.

```
require "facebook.php";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => YOUR_APP_ID,
    'secret' => YOUR_APP_SECRET,
));

$fql = 'SELECT url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, click_count, total_count 
        FROM link_stat WHERE url="http://stackoverflow.com"';

$result = $facebook->api(array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => $fql,
));
```

The `$result` array contains what you need (`like_count` field) and even more :

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [url] => http://stackoverflow.com
        [share_count] => 1356
        [like_count] => 332
        [comment_count] => 538
        [click_count] => 91
        [total_count] => 2226
    )
)
```

Comment: Hi please see the page it has recommended button i need the value http://edition.cnn.com/2011/HEALTH/05/31/who.cell.phones/index.html?hpt=hp_t1

Comment: Hi, if you open the source of the page you can see it is a `<fb:like>` tag. There is no way to differentiate recommendations and likes because it is the same.

Comment: ok then when i use above code for this url it will return 0 values.why? can u please check it.

Comment: Hi Praneeth, that does not come from the PHP script, it is because the link you give is http://edition.cnn.com/... and the link which is shared on Facebook is http://www.cnn.com/... (as Rufinus found). So it is normal that the edition... has no results and the www... has all the results.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use FQL for it.

```
<?php
require_once('../library/Facebook.php');
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '123456789000000',
    'secret' => 'asdf',
    'cookie' => true,
));
$result = $facebook->api(array(
    'method' => 'fql.query',
    'query' => 'select like_count, total_count, share_count, click_count from link_stat where url="http://<url>";'
));
echo $result[0]['total_count'];
?>
```

see http://www.cwd.at/2011/04/facebook-tipp-anzahl-der-fans-die-eine-fan-page-liken/ too.

EDIT: see http://facebook.cwd.at/so.php
For working example with the url you mentioned in the comments. (using the none SDK code snippet)

Comment: No need to load all the Facebook PHP SDK for that !

Comment: @Quentin: not now right, but rumour is, more and more api calls will need access_token to access infos.
And honestly i find it no good practice to use url include in examples for "beginners".

Comment: Oh ok, I read some things like the on [Facebook developers blog](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/509/). So you would recommand to use the SDK for all API calls ?

Comment: Hi please see the page it has recommended button i need the value http://edition.cnn.com/2011/HEALTH/05/31/who.cell.phones/index.html?hpt=hp_t1

Comment: @quntin: i have my own facebook lib, which handels authentification and access_token handling. the main thing to think about is: is it a temoprary marketing page wich is only online a few weeks, or is it to stay longer (months, maybe years) in the the first case its only a matter of personal prefefences, even facebook take a while to implement and change things. but if you have a project which stays online longer, you will want to reduce the maintenance for the project.

Answer (score 1):

To just see the shares you can view/consume http://graph.facebook.com/http://yourdomain.com

For example: http://graph.facebook.com/http://www.apple.com/ipod